# Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Tags: javascript, wordpress

My website http://www.e-sports.tv.br/ is flashing a black screen when it finished loading. I don't know how to solve this, but the Developer Console returned these errors:

```
OPTIONS http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700|Abril+Fatface|Sou…ka|Droid+Sans|Josefin+Sans|Dancing+Script:400,700|Abel|Rokkitt|Droid+Serif 405 (Method Not Allowed) css3-mediaqueries.js?ver=3.6.1:129

OPTIONS http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700|Abril+Fatface|Sou…ka|Droid+Sans|Josefin+Sans|Dancing+Script:400,700|Abel|Rokkitt|Droid+Serif Origin http://www.e-sports.tv.br is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. css3-mediaqueries.js?ver=3.6.1:129
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700|Abril+Fatface|Sou…ka|Droid+Sans|Josefin+Sans|Dancing+Script:400,700|Abel|Rokkitt|Droid+Serif. Origin http://www.e-sports.tv.br is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (index):1

OPTIONS http://s.gravatar.com/css/services.css?ver=2013Octaa 405 (Method Not Allowed) css3-mediaqueries.js?ver=3.6.1:129

OPTIONS http://s.gravatar.com/css/services.css?ver=2013Octaa Origin http://www.e-sports.tv.br is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. css3-mediaqueries.js?ver=3.6.1:129
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://s.gravatar.com/css/services.css?ver=2013Octaa. Origin http://www.e-sports.tv.br is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (index):1

OPTIONS http://s0.wp.com/i/noticons/noticons.css?ver=2.5-201342 Origin http://www.e-sports.tv.br is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. css3-mediaqueries.js?ver=3.6.1:129
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://s0.wp.com/i/noticons/noticons.css?ver=2.5-201342. Origin http://www.e-sports.tv.br is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (index):1

OPTIONS http://s0.wp.com/wp-content/mu-plugins/notes/admin-bar-v2.css?ver=2.5-201342 Origin http://www.e-sports.tv.br is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. css3-mediaqueries.js?ver=3.6.1:129
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://s0.wp.com/wp-content/mu-plugins/notes/admin-bar-v2.css?ver=2.5-201342. Origin http://www.e-sports.tv.br is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (index):1

OPTIONS http://s.gravatar.com/css/hovercard.css?ver=2013Octaa 405 (Method Not Allowed) css3-mediaqueries.js?ver=3.6.1:129

OPTIONS http://s.gravatar.com/css/hovercard.css?ver=2013Octaa Origin http://www.e-sports.tv.br is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. css3-mediaqueries.js?ver=3.6.1:129

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://s.gravatar.com/css/hovercard.css?ver=2013Octaa. Origin http://www.e-sports.tv.br is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (index):1

Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.e-sports.tv.br" from accessing a frame with origin "https://widgets.wp.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.
 external_contentscript_siteoverlay_bin.js:92

Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.e-sports.tv.br" from accessing a frame with origin "http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net". Protocols, domains, and ports must match. external_contentscript_siteoverlay_bin.js:92

Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.e-sports.tv.br" from accessing a frame with origin "https://platform.twitter.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.
```

Can someone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I got similar errors. After trying a lot with dead-ends (crossdomain.xml, etc.) I finally found that the Google Publisher Toolbar was causing the errors. 
It is an error that will not display in the browser of your visitors, only in yours. If you want/need to fix it anyways, remove your domain in the Publisher Toolbar options or disable the Publisher Toolbar completely.